# Select within Select in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to insert records in an output table t2 using values from another table t1. While doing so I also need to use the max of column col3 from t2.

To achieve the same I tried to use a select max(c1) within the select statement of table t1.
The same works in well in SQL. Is there any alternative method to achieve the same in Hive ?

```
INSERT INTO t2 
SELECT t1.c AS col1,
(SELECT MAX(col3)+1 FROM t2) AS col2
FROM t1;
```

This is the error I am getting

```
FAILED: ParseException line 7:1 cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' 'max' in expression specification
```

Comment: Except the problem with MAX calculation, t2 also contains col3 column, you need to provide something to insert in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO t2 
SELECT t1.c AS col1, 
       s.col2, 
       ... you need to provide all columns here
FROM t1
     cross join (select MAX(col3)+1 AS col2 FROM t2) s
;
```

Comment: Thanks @leftjoin , this was such an obvious and simple solution but I was over-thinking! Appreciate you help!